# Inverse of a positive symmetric matrix with large entries

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite, central-limit-theorem

I have a random vector $Z = X_{1} + X_{2} + \ldots + X_{T}$, where each $X_{i}$ is a $n\times 1$ random vector with finite mean and covariance matrix. Each $X_i$ has a different mean and covariance matrix. I have $ L = E[Z'](E[ZZ']^{-1})$, where E is expectation, $E^{-1}(ZZ')$ is inverse of $E[ZZ']$.

Now, if I take $T$ to infinity, what can I say about L? I suspect (after doing some numerical examples) that L will be very small, but is there a way to show it analytically?

Comment: What about the dependence between the $X_i$ ? Are they independent? Are they joint normal? Something else?

Comment: They are dependent.

Comment: Oh and you most certainly need some bounds on means and covariance as $T\rightarrow\infty$ to make sure $E[Z]$ and $E[ZZ']$ exist. What are they?

Comment: I fear you need to know more than "dependent" to conclude something here.

Comment: We do know that mean and covariance of X are finite.

Comment: When you say the $X_i$ are dependent, do you mean the components of $X_i$ are dependent as shown by $\Sigma_i$? Or that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are dependent on each other.  If the latter then you need  to know the dependency

Comment: I mean element of each X are dependent. But X_{t+1} and X_{t+1} are independent. Sorry for confusion.